# Block visability if cck key value is checked

Tags: php, drupal

I have a View and a block display. I would like for this block to be on every page but give the author the ability to turn it off with a cck field. What is the best way to do this? I thought about about creating a cck text field using a an on/off checkbox. Then in the View add an argument to hide the block if the key value is unchecked. I cant figure out the argument for key values. I also thought about creating a vocabulary, then use the mass tag module to tag every node with a term, the authors could then remove that term if the want. And use block display php to only display the block if the term is present. Could the Context module be a solution?

Comment: Which version of Drupal do you use ?!

Comment: Where would you be providing the checkbox?
Do you mean users can manage the visibility of their own content in the block, per node?